# Include all selected types, filter out duplicate where primaryType takes precedence

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to accomplish is select from a table and return all the records 
where the Type matches one of the parameter types. Remove duplicates with the primaryType
being the record of choice if found, if not then a single record from one of the other type arguments.
The order doesn't matter for the other types although it would be nice (can pick @secondType or @thirdType).
This is a POC project so if I need to add or change things to make it easier/faster I'm open to ideas!

```
NOTE: UUID and PARTID are alphanumeric. 
DECLARE  @primaryType varchar(32) = 'diamond';
DECLARE  @secondType varchar(32)  = 'gold';
DECLARE  @thirdType varchar(32)   = 'nickel';


SettingName     Type        PARTID  UUID
----------------------------------------
Alpha           diamond     123     123     <== Returned because the primaryType takes precedence 
Alpha - g       gold        123     321     <== Not returned because it would be a duplicate, primaryType wins
Charlie         diamond     456     456     <== Returned; no duplicate partid and is in type list.
Delta - c       copper      789     789     <== Not returned becuase it's not in type list
Echo - g        gold        987     987     <== Returned because no duplicate partid and is in type list
```

Desired result...

```
Alpha           diamond     123     123     <== Returned because the primaryType takes precedence 
Charlie         diamond     456     456     <== Returned no duplicate partid and is in type list.
Echo - g        gold        987     987     <== Returned because no duplicate partid and is in type list
```

I've tried something like the code below as well as other code but just can't seem to nail it down.

```
 SELECT * from
    ( SELECT SettingName, Type, PARTID, UUID
            ,row_number() over (partition by PARTID order by Type ) idx
      FROM Settings
      WHERE
        (Type = @primaryType OR Type = @secondType OR Type = @thirdType) 
    ) a where idx = 1
```

Where the code above gets hung up is the order by Type can return the wrong result because the @primaryType may be further down the list when sorted. Which would return @secondType or @thirdType depending on the sorted result.

Comment: Hey @bluesektor, welcome to StackOverflow. This is an interesting question. It may be useful to provide an example of the results for your current query given the sample data set provided; I find that helps readers quickly understand the difference between the desired result and the actual result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just use the @Type values in the over(order by) clause to create custom ordering/precedence.

```
declare @t table
(
id int identity,
SettingName varchar(50),
Type varchar(50),
PARTID varchar(50),
UUID varchar(50)
);

insert into @t(SettingName, Type, PARTID, UUID)
values
('Alpha', 'diamond', '123', '123'),   --<== Returned because the primaryType takes precedence 
('Alpha - g', 'gold', '123', '321'),   --<== Not returned because it would be a duplicate, primaryType wins
('Charlie', 'diamond', '456', '456'),  --<== Returned; no duplicate partid and is in type list.
('Delta - c', 'copper', '789', '789'), -- <== Not returned becuase it's not in type list
('Echo - g', 'gold', '987', '987'); 

DECLARE  @primaryType varchar(32) = 'diamond';
DECLARE  @secondType varchar(32)  = 'gold';
DECLARE  @thirdType varchar(32)   = 'nickel';


select * 
from
(
    select *, 
        row_number() over(partition by PARTID order by case Type when  @primaryType then 1 when @secondType then 2 when @thirdType then 3 else 4 end, len(Type), id /*id as final tie-breaker*/) as rownum
    from @t
    where Type in (@primaryType, @secondType, @thirdType)
) as a
--where a.rownum = 1
```